# Using jquery-textcomplete without auto selecting first option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) on a text field.  Everything works great, but I want to mimic how Twitter provides autocomplete for search and when you start typing '@'.  On Twitter, when you perform a search - a dropdown appears and no items are selected unless the user presses the 'down' key on the keyboard or clicks with the mouse to make the selection.  If no selection is made and you press 'enter' then Twitter either takes you to a search results page or if you are composing a tweet and press 'enter' a new line is added.

Right now my code works great but jquery-textcomplete automatically adds active class to the first choice when loading the dropdown menu.  If the user presses 'enter' without making a selection, it assumes you want the first choice and executes the me.loadPage(value); function.

Here's my code:

```
$('.elastic_search').textcomplete([{ // mention strategy
  match: /(^|\s)(\w+ ?\w+ ?\w+)$/i,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    //me.options.skip = 0;
    //me.options.state = "firstview";

    $.getJSON('/elastic/search', {
      q: term,
      //user_id: userObj.user_id,
      //skip: me.options.skip
      limit: 10,

    }).done(function(resp) {
      callback(resp);
    }).fail(function() {
      callback([]);
    });
  },
  css: function() {
    return {
      'background-color': 'green'
    };
  },
  replace: function(value) {
    return '$1' + $.trim(value._source.username);
  },
  template: function(value) {
    value._source.profilepic = makeImageSize(value._source.profilepic, '35x35');
    if (value._source && value._source.link_type === 'hashcode') {
      return '<div data-type="hashcode">#' + value._source.text + '</div>';
    } else if (value._source.type === 'code') {
      return '<div data-type="entity"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + value._source.profilepic + '" /></div><div class="col-xs-9 resultname">' + (('<b>' + value._source.fullname + '</b>' || ' ') + ' We#' + value._source.wecode) + '</div></div>';
    } else if (value._source) {
      return '<div data-type="entity"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + value._source.profilepic + '" /></div><div class="col-xs-9 resultname">' + ((value.highlight.fullname || ' ') + ' @' + value._source.username) + '</div></div>';
    }
  }
}, { // mention strategy
  match: /(^|\s)we#(\w*)$/i,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    //me.options.skip = 0;
    //me.options.state = "firstview";
    $.getJSON('/elastic/search', {
      q: term,
      fields: ['wecode^4'],
      wecode_complete: "yes",
      //user_id: userObj.user_id,
      //skip: me.options.skip
      limit: 10
    }).done(function(resp) {

      callback(resp);
    }).fail(function() {

      callback([]);
    });
  },
  css: function() {
    return {
      'background-color': 'green'
    };
  },
  replace: function(value) {
    return '$1' + $.trim(value._source.username);
  },
  template: function(value) {
    value._source.profilepic = makeImageSize(value._source.profilepic, '35x35');
    if (value._source && value._source.link_type === 'hashcode') {
      return '<div data-type="hashcode">#' + value._source.text + '</div>';
    } else if (value._source.type === 'code') {
      return '<div data-type="entity"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + value._source.profilepic + '" /></div><div class="col-xs-9 resultname">' + (('<b>' + value._source.fullname + '</b>' || ' ') + ' We#' + value._source.wecode) + '</div></div>';
    } else if (value._source) {
      return '<div data-type="entity"><div class="col-xs-2"><img src="' + value._source.profilepic + '" /></div><div class="col-xs-9 resultname">' + (('<b>' + value._source.fullname + '</b>' || ' ') + ' @' + value._source.username) + '</div></div>';
    }
  }
}], {
  appendTo: $('.search-container'),
  className: 'dropdown-absolute',
  zIndex: '100001',
  placement: 'absleft'
}).on({
  'textComplete:select': function(e, value, strategy) {
    //me.options.hashtags.push(value);
    //This Discover Cards Need to be formatted.
    me.loadPage(value);
  }
```

I have found that commenting out line 411 in jquery.textcomplete.js will prevent the first item from having the .active class on the frontend, however this is not a solution because if you press 'enter' it behaves as if the first item was selected, so the first item is still the active choice.

```
 render: function (zippedData) {
  var contentsHtml = this._buildContents(zippedData);
  var unzippedData = $.map(this.data, function (d) { return d.value; });
  if (this.data.length) {
    this._renderHeader(unzippedData);
    this._renderFooter(unzippedData);
    if (contentsHtml) {
      this._renderContents(contentsHtml);
      // this._activateIndexedItem();  // comment this kind of works
    }
    this._setScroll();
  } else if (this.shown) {
    this.deactivate();
  }
}
```

My question is, how do I prevent the first choice from being selected?